# Is "norm" equivalent to "Euclidean distance"?

Tags: python, arrays, math, numpy, euclidean-distance

I am not sure whether "norm" and "Euclidean distance" mean the same thing. Please could you help me with this distinction.

I have an `n` by `m` array `a`, where `m` > 3. I want to calculate the Eculidean distance between the second data point `a[1,:]` to all the other points (including itself). So I used the `np.linalg.norm`, which outputs the norm of two given points. But I don't know if this is the right way of getting the EDs.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0 ,0 ], [1, 1 , 1, 1],[2,2, 2, 3], [3,5, 1, 5]])
N = a.shape[0] # number of row
pos = a[1,:] # pick out the second data point. 
dist = np.zeros((N,1), dtype=np.float64)

for i in range(N):
    dist[i]= np.linalg.norm(a[i,:] - pos)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) is a function that takes a vector as an input and returns a scalar value that can be interpreted as the "size", "length" or "magnitude" of that vector. More formally, norms  are defined as having the following mathematical properties:

- They scale multiplicatively, i.e. *Norm(a·**v**) = |a|·Norm(**v**)* for any scalar *a*
- They satisfy the triangle inequality, i.e. *Norm(**u** + **v**) ≤ Norm(**u**) + Norm(**v**)*
- The norm of a vector is zero if and only if it is the zero vector, i.e. *Norm(**v**) = 0 ⇔ **v** = **0***

The Euclidean norm (also known as the L² norm) is just one of many different norms - there is also the max norm, the Manhattan norm etc. The L² norm of a single vector is equivalent to the Euclidean distance from that point to the origin, and the L² norm of the difference between two vectors is equivalent to the Euclidean distance between the two points.

---

As **@nobar**'s answer says, `np.linalg.norm(x - y, ord=2)` (or just `np.linalg.norm(x - y)`) will give you Euclidean distance between the vectors `x` and `y`.

Since you want to compute the Euclidean distance between `a[1, :]` and every other row in `a`, you could do this a lot faster by eliminating the `for` loop and broadcasting over the rows of `a`:

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(a[1:2] - a, axis=1)
```

It's also easy to compute the Euclidean distance yourself using broadcasting:

```
dist = np.sqrt(((a[1:2] - a) ** 2).sum(1))
```

The fastest method is probably [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dist = cdist(a[1:2], a)[0]
```

---

Some timings for a (1000, 1000) array:

```
a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

%timeit np.linalg.norm(a[1:2] - a, axis=1)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.43 ms per loop

%timeit np.sqrt(((a[1:2] - a) ** 2).sum(1))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 ms per loop

%timeit cdist(a[1:2], a)[0]
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 ms per loop

# check that all 3 methods return the same result
d1 = np.linalg.norm(a[1:2] - a, axis=1)
d2 = np.sqrt(((a[1:2] - a) ** 2).sum(1))
d3 = cdist(a[1:2], a)[0]

assert np.allclose(d1, d2) and np.allclose(d1, d3)
```

Answer (score 5):

The concept of a "norm" is a generalized idea in mathematics which, when applied to vectors (or vector differences), broadly represents some measure of length.  There are various different approaches to computing a norm, but the one called Euclidean distance is called the "2-norm" and is based on applying an exponent of 2 (the "square"), and after summing applying an exponent of 1/2 (the "square root").

---

It's a bit cryptic in [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), but you get Euclidean distance between two vectors by setting the parameter `ord=2`.

> `sum(abs(x)**ord)**(1./ord)`

becomes `sqrt(sum(x**2))`.

Note: as pointed out by @Holt, the default value is `ord=None`, which is documented to compute the "2-norm" for vectors.  This is, therefore, equivalent to `ord=2` (Euclidean distance).

Comment: You also get it with the default `None` value.

Comment: @Holt: Thanks, I didn't notice that.  The default is `None` which computes the "2-norm", presumably matching `ord=2`.

Comment: Seems a shame to have all this discussion of the "2-norm" without mentioning it's most famous form: The Pythagorean theorem.